# How to set MaterialToolbar as ActionBar without support libraries

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

Is there a way to set a `MaterialToolbar` as an `Activity`'s `ActionBar`? Whenever I try to set mine, Android Studio keeps asking for a `Toolbar` from the support library.

> Required: Toolbar? - Found: MaterialToolbar

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/myAppBarLayout">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/myCollapsingToolbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/myToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

**Kotlin**

```
class MainActivity : Activity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.collapsingtoolbar_and_recyclerview)

        val mCoordinatorLayout = findViewById<CoordinatorLayout>(R.id.myCoordinatorLayout)
        val mCollapsingToolbarLayout = findViewById<CollapsingToolbarLayout>(R.id.myCollapsingToolbarLayout)
        val mToolbar = findViewById<MaterialToolbar>(R.id.myToolbar)

        // ...Do other stuff here
        setActionBar(mCollapsingToolbarLayout)
        mCollapsingToolbarLayout.title = "Hello, world!"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setActionBar()` requires a **framework** `Toolbar`. `MaterialToolbar` correctly extends the AndroidX `Toolbar`, which means you must use `AppCompatActivity` and `setSupportActionBar()` and not `Activity` and `setActionBar()`.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.collapsingtoolbar_and_recyclerview)

        //[...]
        val toolbar = findViewById<MaterialToolbar>(R.id.myToolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        // ...Do other stuff here
        supportActionBar.title = "My MainActivity"
        supportActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Well that's not ideal if trying to move my project to Material Design Components. API 29 is my project minimum.

Comment: You are already pulling in `AppCompat` as a dependency, the Material themes already extend from the `AppCompat` themes, etc., etc. You'll also find that ~all of [Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture) and basically any of the other building blocks of modern Android all *also* require you use something other than the base `Activity` class - you get ~nothing by setting your minSdkVersion to 29 that you wouldn't also get by setting your minSdkVersion to 24 or even 21.

Comment: I'm not using that dependency at all + I don't need to support older versions of Android.

Comment: AppCompat is a transitive dependency of Material Design Components, so you are using it if you are using Material Design Components. Whether you support older versions of Android or not, ~none of the recommended tools you use in modern Android development are tied to the Android framework in any meaningful way.

Comment: So should AppCompat be used for all activities I create? What would happen if I don't use the AppCompat dependency?

Comment: Yes, you should be using `AppCompatActivity` for all activities. If you are using Material Design Components, you don't get a choice - AppCompat is a required dependency of Material Design Components and all of the theming, styles, and APIs require it.

Comment: As of 2020, should I be using `AppCompat` or `MaterialComponents` derived themes for my app?

Comment: Yes. You'd use `MaterialComponents` if using Material Design Components (as is required) or `AppCompat` if you are not using Material Design Components.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare also mToolbar as MaterialToolbar:

```
val mToolbar: MaterialToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar)
```

or use view binding, see https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
```

and in onCreate():

```
binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
setContentView(binding.root)
setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
```